# bxslider with thumbnails. I need to fix the position of thumbs

Tags: jquery, ajax, bxslider

I am using bxslider to show my sliders. These sliders has thumbnails but I am unable to fix the position of thumbnails, these are over main image.

You can view my live site 
http://jardinesyriegosdelsur.com/portafolio.php?g=8 or you can choose any gallery from left side. The site is in spanish but all coding is in english.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your css as below:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    /* bottom: -200px; */
    top: 480px;
}
```

and you will get a look like below:

[image]

Comment: but what about other links? http://jardinesyriegosdelsur.com/portafolio.php?g=7 or http://jardinesyriegosdelsur.com/portafolio.php?g=4 these are dynamic sliders

Comment: keep small size images for thumbnails so that page will take less time to load.